# Is this question fit for Writing SE or EL&U?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, asking-questions, off-topic

Here's is a simplification of the question, below it is why I an unsure where it should go:

> Is this a metaphorical or figurative sentence: "His heart was filled with anguish, anger and sorrow".
>
> Is this metaphorical writing, or figurative writing? It isn't really a metaphor, as it isn't translatable to direct speech, right? I think it is figurative, as it isn't using the literal meaning of words, as your actual heart isn't the center for emotion in your body. But I'm not sure. Is it perhaps both?

Now, this question does heavily relate to writing. It is asking a question about metaphors and figurative speech. But it is effectively about the definitions of these things.

So, is this question a Writing SE or EL&U question. Or is it (conceptually) fit for neither? Or is it fit for both? If so, which one would it be best on?

---

[Doesn't this question belong on "English Language & Usage"?](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2033/doesnt-this-question-belong-on-english-language-usage)

Here's a related question where I ask the same question about a different question, where the conclusion, provided by Cyn, was that the question in question was fit for both sites.

(just wrote *question* four times in that sentence)

Comment: I take it you have already looked at https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This question should be on English Language & Usage and not on Writing.

It's not about writing.  It's information that might be useful to a writer, but then is information from a wide variety of places.

The question about the word "temping" is different.  This is a question from a writer asking if a term will have the same meaning across English dialects.  I stand by my earlier response that it could work here on Writing or over at English.

As you point out, in the question about metaphor, it's asking for a definition.  Not about incorporating it into writing in any way.

Answer (score 4):

## It fits better on EL&U

*Disclaimer: I am not active on EL&U and not 100% certain on their guidelines.*

If I saw this question on Writing.SE I would vote to close as off-topic. One of our off topic guidelines is:

> The strictly interpreted correctness of English grammar or syntax rules (please ask those on English Language & Usage, instead).

I feel this question falls safely under that banner.

The difference to the linked meta is the context for the question. The other question asked "is this term too culturally specific for my writing?". Your question is asked to classify a sentence based on grammar rules. That isn't something we do here. I suggest you ask it on EL&U and see what kind of response you get. Users there will be able to to help you edit it to fit their format.

If you want to ask it here you will need to put it in the context of creating a written work. I'm not exactly sure how you could rephrase it to fit here but it is possible.